# Is it a good way to get Count on Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public class BuscaDiretaBusiness
{
    PortalIOEntities portalIO = new PortalIOEntities();

    public IQueryable CarregaAlias(out int ItemsCount)
    {
        var query = from a in portalIO.DO_CadernoBuscaDiretaAlias
                    select new
                    {
                        a.CDP_ID,
                        a.CDA_Alias,
                        a.DO_CadernoDeParaBuscaDireta.CDP_NomeCaderno
                    };
        ItemsCount = query.Count();
        return query;
    }
}
```

Will it make two selects on DataBase?

Comment: Why not just return the IQueryable.  Do you need to pass in an out parameter?  And yes, that is the way to get count of items

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That method will only hit the DB once, with a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) …`. But if you try to enumerate the resulting `IQueryable` in any way (like calling `ToArray()` on it or using it in a `foreach`), it will make another DB query.

You should probably only return the `IQueryable`. If the consumer needs all the items, it will call `ToArray()` or similar, which will make one DB query and then look at the `Length` of the result (which of course won't make another query). If the consumer needs only part of the result (e.g. it will call `Take(100)`) and it also needs the total count, it will call `Count()` itself. This will mean there will be two queries, but I think it can't be done differently.

Also, you probably should not be returning a collection of an anonymous type from a method, because it's hard to use.

Answer (score 3):

You're fine.  It will only make 1 query.

Plus dreza is right, don't pass back "count" through the out parameter.  It isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Typically that's the correct way to get a count, yes. Linq2sql and Linq2Nh for instance will see the Count operator and create a COUNT(*) query at TSQL level. So it'll hit the db once when .Count() is called on the IQueryable, returning a single row containing the count.

Note that it'd hit the db again if you call .Count() again. Your method appears to have two responsibilities at present - I'd just return the required IQueryable and call the .Count() on it elsewhere. Then you can still easily grab the IQueryable if you actually need to enumerate the results later